# How to make one column always highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code. How can I edit my code so the third pricing plan is always highlighted blue? And if I click another table, the previous one (including the third) unhighlights? Thank you in advance!

```js
$('.pricing-customer').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.pricing-customer {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}
p.pricing-number {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fead0d;
}
p.pricing-monthes {
  color: #5e6977;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ee;
}
p.emails {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.pricing-customer:hover, .pricing-customer.active {

 background-color: #333;
}
.pricing-customer:hover p , .pricing-customer.active p{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>

<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>

<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying different class to the third box, have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$('.pricing-customer').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active default');
});
```

```css
.pricing-customer {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}
p.pricing-number {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fead0d;
}
p.pricing-monthes {
  color: #5e6977;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ee;
}
p.emails {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.pricing-customer:hover, .pricing-customer.active {

 background-color: #333;
}
.pricing-customer:hover p , .pricing-customer.active p{
  color: #fff;
}

.pricing-customer.default {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>

<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>

<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center default">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! It works perfectly for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Morgari It's my pleasure!

Comment: This doesn't work - if you select the 3rd column and then select another one, the blue highlight disappears from the 3rd column (because you remove the `default` class but never add it again)

Comment: @SauravRastogi You may be right - When I read 'always highlighted blue' then I assume it mean it should always be highlighted blue. In your solution, the 3rd column is highlighted blue until you select something and after that it will never be blue again

Comment: @Beno The question also says that "when we select, it should remove the highlighted section as well." Please read the full question.

Answer (score 2):

First and simplest would be to just add the `active` class to the third plan in your HTML. That will highlight it initially, then remove the highlighting once somebody clicks a different plan.

If you really have your heart set on blue for the third plan, I'd suggest adding another CSS class, maybe `active-blue` or something similar, and changing your code to

```
$('.pricing-customer').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active active-blue');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a new class to the 3rd column called `pricing-customer-blue` which has a different hover and active background color.

```js
$('.pricing-customer').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.pricing-customer {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}
p.pricing-number {
  font-size: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fead0d;
}
p.pricing-monthes {
  color: #5e6977;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ee;
}
p.emails {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.pricing-customer:hover, .pricing-customer.active {

 background-color: #333;
}
.pricing-customer-blue:hover, .pricing-customer-blue.active{
  background: blue;
}
.pricing-customer:hover p , .pricing-customer.active p{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>

<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>

<div class="pricing-customer col-sm-12 col-sm-3 text-center pricing-customer-blue">
  <h3><?php echo $t_title; ?></h3>
  <p class="pricing-number">$ 70</p>
  <br>
  <p class="pricing-monthes">per week/month</p>
  <p class="pricing-emails">100 000 emails</p>
</div>
```